# Facebook login with email and password working on a Java project, but not on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, http

I'm developing an Android application that requires the user to log in on Facebook by inputting his email and password through a custom interface (not through a WebView popup, like the Facebook SDK provides).

I have succeeded in doing so in a Java project by using HTTP connections to send form data and receive an access token, but when I ported the same code in my Android application, the HTTP connections lead to the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page
```

I have done the required app signing and key hash registering, both debug and release.

I am using code almost identical to this example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

Any idea why I am getting the above URL when running the same code in Android?

Comment: Proxying username and passwords using your own view controller is against the Platform Policies (I.2) - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: I see. So they probably implemented some scripts to prevent this from happening, at least for mobile apps. Thanks for the answer.